# Why does image and text both move when I apply padding to just the text?

Tags: css

I've been playing around to learn and have kinda hit a wall which I can't seem to answer. I want to try and have the text 3/4s the way down of the image.

I've determined that it must be something to do with inline-block as the padding works when the display is block but the text is below the image so it's not as useful.

```
<img src="img" alt="Image" width="100" height="67"/>
<p style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 20px;">Test</p>
```

Before:

[image: Before Image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely because of the `display: inline-block;` which causes the `img` and `p` to move together as a single line. Are you trying to move just the `p` down while leaving the position of the `img` unchanged?

Comment: Ah makes sense. Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'd like to move p down a few pixels so that instead of being at halfway, the text would be 3/4 down the image's length and the image would stay in the same place.

Comment: I added an answer that better explains why `inline-block` causes the behavior you're seeing. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, elements that are displayed `inline` or `inline-block` are aligned to the bottom of the line. Therefore, as you increase `margin-top` to `p`, the bottom of the `p` moves down causing the `img` to move as well. You can prevent this by adding `vertical-align: top;`, which affects elements that are inline with the `p`.

```html
<img src="img" alt="Image" width="100" height="67"/>
<p style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 20px; vertical-align: top;">Test</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!